# How to assign @Inputs of a @Directive using Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to create a Reactive Form using the `FormBuilder` from `@angular/forms`, but I stumbled upon a case regarding custom validating @Directives, @Inputs and the `FormBuilder`.

In the following code, I have my custom MatchValidator Directive, the question is, How can I assign values to the the @Input variables when defining my `FormGroup`?

```js
// My custom Directive
@Directive( {
    selector: "[cw-match]",
    providers: [ { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: MatchValidator, multi: true } ]
} )
export class MatchValidator implements Validator,OnChanges {
    @Input() matchTo; // <— How to assign values to this properties using formBuilder?
    @Input() control;

    ngOnChanges( changes:SimpleChanges ) {
        this.control.control.updateValueAndValidity( false, true );
    }

    validate( control:AbstractControl ):{ [ key:string ]:any; } {
        if( !control.value ) return  null;
        return ( control.value === this.matchTo )? null : { "matchError": true };
    }
}

// My component 
@Component( /*… */)
export class UserDetailsComponent implements OnChanges, AfterViewInit {

    constructor( formBuilder: FormBuilder ){
        this.userDetailsForm = this.formBuilder.group( {
            slug: [ "", SlugValidator ],
            basicCredentials: this.formBuilder.group( {
                username: [ "", Validators.required ],
                password: [ "", MatchValidator ], // <— How can I assign the matchTo and control values the @Input properties of the directive asks for?
                repeatPassword: [ "" ],
            } )
        } );
    }
}
```

Is it even possible to assign the @Input values of a Validating @Directive using FormBuilder??

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. `@Input` properties are intended to be used specifically in template bindings, not from the code the way you want.

**EDIT**: Also, angular does not actually expect that validator can "change its mind" based on something other than the value being validated, so even if there was a way to specify it in form builder it should not work correctly anyway.